# What's the difference between Matcher.lookingAt() and find()?

Tags: java, regex

I am looking at Java regex tutorial, the title pretty much explains itself. It looks like Matcher.lookingAt() is trying to match the entire String. Is that true?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The [documentation for Matcher.lookingAt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#lookingAt--) clearly explains the region `lookingAt` tries to match:

> Like the `matches` method, this method always starts at the beginning of the region; unlike that method, it does not require that the entire region be matched.

So no, `lookingAt` does not require matching the whole string.  Then what's the difference between `lookingAt` and `find`?  From the [Matcher Javadoc overview](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html):

> - The `matches` method attempts to match the entire input sequence against the pattern.
> - The `lookingAt` method attempts to match the input sequence, starting at the beginning, against the pattern.
> - The `find` method scans the input sequence looking for the next subsequence that matches the pattern.

`lookingAt` always starts at the beginning, but `find` will scan for a starting position.

Viewed another way, `matches` has a fixed start and end, `lookingAt` has a fixed start but a variable end, and `find` has a variable start and end.

Comment: Thanks the details are nice! :) Also Using the matches and lookingAt Methods of the tutorial also touches this topic: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/matcher.html

Answer (score 5):

`lookingAt()` always starts checking from the beginning, and returns `true` when it comes across a match.

`find()` can find multiple matches, because it stores its current position, much like an iterator.

About `find()` from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29:

> This method starts at the beginning of this matcher's region, or, if a previous invocation of the method was successful and the matcher has not since been reset, at the first character not matched by the previous match.

Answer (score 0):

May be some code would make this easier to grasp:

```
    @Test
    void testFind() {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("abc");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("abc def mno abc");

        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("found from : " + m.start() + " to " + m.end());
        }
    }

    @Test
    void testLookingAt() {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("abc");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("abc def mno abc");

        if (m.lookingAt()) {
            System.out.println("lookingAt hit " + m.start() + " to " + m.end());
        }
    }

    @Test
    void testMatches() {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("abc");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("abc def mno abc");

        if (m.matches()) {
            System.out.println("matches");
        }
    }
```

As you can see `find` is like an iterator, in our sample it found two tokens. `lookingAt` looks from the beginning and and `matches` tries to match against the entire input (that's why that statement is not printed at all)