# java regex tell which column not match

Tags: java, regex

Good day,

My java code is as follow:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9$&+,:;=\\[\\]{}?@#|\\\\'<>._^*()%!/~\"`  -]*$");
String i = "f698fec0-dd89-11e8-b06b-â˜º";
Matcher tagmatch = p.matcher(i);
System.out.println("tagmatch is " + tagmatch.find());
```

As expected, the answer will be false, because there is `â˜º` character inside. However, I would like to show the column number that not match. For this example, it should show column 25th having the invalid character.

May I know how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove anchors from your regex and then use [`Matcher#end()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#lookingAt--) method to get the position where it stopped the previous match like this:

```bash
String i = "f698fec0-dd89-11e8-b06b-â˜º";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\w$&+,:;=\\[\\]{}?@#|\\\\'<>.^*()%!/~\"`  -]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(i);
if (m.lookingAt() && i.length() > m.end()) { 
   System.out.println("Match <" + m.group() + "> failed at: " + m.end());
}
```

**Output:**

```bash
Match <f698fec0-dd89-11e8-b06b-> failed at: 24
```

**PS**: I have used `lookingAt()` to ensure that we match the pattern starting from the beginning of the region. You can use `find()` as well to get the next match anywhere or else keep the start anchor in pattern as

```
"^[\\w$&+,:;=\\[\\]{}?@#|\\\\'<>.^*()%!/~\"`  -]+"
```

and use `find()` to effectively make it behave like the above code with `lookingAt()`.

[Read difference between `lookingAt()` and `find()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30008397/whats-the-difference-between-matcher-lookingat-and-find)

I have refactored your regex to use `\w` instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and used quantifier `+` (meaning match 1 or more) instead of `*` (meaning match 0 or more) to avoid returning success for zero-length matches.

Comment: Or just keep the start anchor.

Comment: Note that `lookingAt()`/`find()` will always return true because the `*` matches zero-length strings. You'll want to compare `end()` to `i.length()` to check if it's a full match or not.

Comment: Good point, i have now suggested to use `+` instead of `*`

Comment: Your code doesn't print whether the expected pattern was matched. If there is an unexpected character at the beginning, nothing is output. Otherwise, it prints something, but I don't know if the whole thing matched.

Comment: @anubhava , is this one possible applicable on the opposite site? meaning I put $ at behind my regex and wan to make the .find() is false. and only find out which column giving problem.

Comment: If you put `$` then `find()/lookingAt()` will fail and then you can't use `end()` method as calling that would throw exception `ava.lang.IllegalStateException: No match available`

Comment: @ﾓｷｬﾃﾞ: I have added `else` block to print `No match!!` for failure case.

Comment: Only if you consider a partial match success, which doesn't appear to be OP's intent. See my previous comment.

Comment: @shmosel: I get your point, have added length check in answer.